# Linking my application against a library in Boost JamFile

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to build my project using b2 tool. My current problem is I want to specify the library to which my application links against in the JamFile. I am able to do that in the command line when calling the b2 command as the following:

```
b2 variant=release link=static  toolset=gcc include=mylib/ linkflags="-L mylib/ -lerror -lwrappers"
```

But I want to specify this command in the JamFile, can anyone give me the syntax how to do that?